# PreparedStatement sets java.util.Date and java.sql.Date without Time information into Mysql dateTime column

Tags: java, mysql

How come that `java.sql.PreparedStatement#setDate` on dateTime mysql column always results in Date format like `2012-10-16 00:00:00`  without Time information ? I'm storing Date in a loop like this :

```
protected Date getIncrementedDateTime() {
    additionalTime += 1000;
    return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + additionalTime);
}


preparedStatement.setDate(j, new java.sql.Date(getIncrementedDateTime().getTime());
```

I debugged the values, but mysql database always have 2012-10-16 00:00:00 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation for [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

> A thin wrapper around a millisecond value that allows JDBC to identify this as an SQL DATE value. [...]
>
> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

Basically, for a datetime column you should probably be using a different type, e.g. [`Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html). (That's not ideal in other ways, but it's likely to be a better fit...)

Comment: Timestamp doesn't go with 'dateTime' column type right ? Incorrect datetime value: '16:16:51' for column ... So that I need to use 'timeStamp' column type and Timestamp data type ?

Comment: @Sloin: I *suspect* that `Timestamp` will actually work fine with a datetime column. It's basically an omission in JDBC here, but `Timestamp` is probably as close as you can get.

Comment: You're right, java.sql.Timestamp and ps.setTimestamp(j, (Timestamp) value);  works fine with 'dateTime' column type

Comment: @Sloin Timestamp should work just fine. Try doing this: preparedStatement.setDate(j, new java.sql.Timestamp(getIncrementedDateTime().getTime());

Answer (score 0):

A java.sql.Date is just a date -- no time. Do not confuse it with java.util.Date, which includes time information. You might want to look at java.sql.Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

It is base on the data type of your table's column. Try to use `TimeStamp` or `Time` according to Database Server.